# JavaScript - change value of two elements from a list

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, list

I want to change the values of two elements from a list, it's hard to explain so I'll put it like this.

I have a list that looks like this

```
Adam Tyson
Emil Johnsson
Fredrick Connor
Lars Hamilton
```

I want to put it in a for loop, like this.

```
for(var i = 0; i < 1000; i++) {
  document.getelementbyid('firstname').innerHTML = param[0];  
  document.getelementbyid('lastname').innerHTML = param[1]; 
  submit();
}
```

But I have no idea how I can make the firstname equal e.g **param[0]**. And also, once it has submitted that it will jump to line 2, and then 3, etcetera and keep doing the same thing. What I basically want to do is submit a form with all these names using a loop.

Any ideas?

Comment: Read about AJAX, or seems like this is what you want to do. Perhaps you want to use something like [jQuery.post()](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.post/).

Comment: `getelementbyid` must be `getElementById`. Also, the `for`-loop makes zero sense as of now because you're not using `i`inside, which means you keep repeating exactly the same code.

Comment: OP, wrt AJAX: you don't necessarily need to add the data to the HTML form first and then submit the form. If the server allows it you can just submit a stringified version of the array/object instead. `JSON.stringify(arr)`.

Comment: Please post and update https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve Put your HTML, your source of "list", any (other) code you have tried.  Please also include the exact results you expect.

Comment: I agree with others that what you describe is typically done via Ajax via a POST - scroll down here for an example: http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/ or here for a shorthand version https://api.jquery.com/jquery.post/

Answer (score 0):

What is understand actually you have list of names and you want to show all to store the names of the list then you need to post them. I think you will first have to create the first name last name for each rows 
like given below

```
var parent = document.getElementById("parentDiv"); // this is my assumption please change as per your need
for(var i = 0; i < 1000; i++) {
  var firstNameFinal = firstName +i;
  var firstNameInput = document.createElement("input");
  firstNameInput.setAttribute('type', 'text');
  firstNameInput.setAttribute('id', 'firstNameFinal');
  parent.appendChild(firstNameInput);
  var lastnameFinal =  lastname + i;
  var lastNameInput = document.createElement("input");
  lastNameInput.setAttribute('type', 'text');
  lastNameInput.setAttribute('id', 'lastnameFinal');
  parent.appendChild(lastNameInput);
  document.getelementbyid('firstNameFinal').innerHTML = param[0];  
  document.getelementbyid('lastnameFinal').innerHTML = param[1]; 
}
  submit();
```

Please reply..